# Calculating glut framerate using clocks_per_sec much too slow

Tags: c++, opengl, time, glut, frame-rate

I'm trying to calculate the framerate of a GLUT window by calling a custom CalculateFrameRate method I made at the beginning of my Display() callback function. I call glutPostRedisplay() after calculations I perform every frame so Display() gets called for every frame.

I also have an int numFrames that increments every frame (every time glutPostRedisplay gets called) and I print that out as well. My CalculateFrameRate method calculates a rate of about 7 fps but if I look at a stopwatch and compare it to how quickly my numFrames incrementor increases, the framerate is easily 25-30 fps.

I can't seem to figure out why there is such a discrepancy. I've posted my CalcuateFrameRate method below

```
clock_t lastTime;
int numFrames;

//GLUT Setup callback
void Renderer::Setup()
{
    numFrames = 0;
    lastTime = clock();  
}

//Called in Display() callback every time I call glutPostRedisplay()
void CalculateFrameRate()
{
    clock_t currentTime = clock();
    double diff = currentTime - lastTime;
    double seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    double frameRate = 1.0 / seconds;
    std::cout<<"FRAMERATE: "<<frameRate<<endl;

    numFrames ++;
    std::cout<<"NUM FRAMES: "<<numFrames<<endl;
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `clock` (except in Windows) gives you the CPU-time uses, so if you are not spinning the CPU for the entire frame-time, then it will give you a lower time than expected. Conversely, if you have 16 cores running 16 of your threads flat out, the time reported by `clock` will be 16 times the actual time.

You can use `std::chrono::steady_clock`, `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, or if you are using Linux/Unix, `gettimeofday` (which gives you microosecond resolution).

Here's a couple of snippets of how to use `gettimeofday` to measure milliseconds:

```
double time_to_double(timeval *t)
{
    return (t->tv_sec + (t->tv_usec/1000000.0)) * 1000.0;
}

double time_diff(timeval *t1, timeval *t2)
{
    return time_to_double(t2) - time_to_double(t1);
}

gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
... do stuff ...
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
cout << "Time taken: " << time_diff(&t1, &t2) << "ms" << endl;
```

Here's a piece of code to show how to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 ... stuff goes here ... 
auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
auto t1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff);
```

Comment: Thanks! Using your first suggestion it calculates my new framerates as being between 25-30 fms which is consistent with the speed I was calculating with my stopwatch.

Comment: On Linux **don't** use gettimeofday, because the value reported by that function is subject to adjustments (NTP, user changed the clock, etc). *You want to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, …)`.

Comment: For the purpose of getting a timestamp to calculate frame-rate during development, `gettimeofday` will be fine - because happening upon the erroneous things are a relatively rare occurrance. If you are writing an application that uses time to determine for example the progress of the enemy during the game, it's clearly not great to use `gettimeofday` for the reasons stated.